# HTML CSS Little Error Top white bar & Color Differences

Tags: html, css, colors, space

At me website ([mikroboards.de](http://mikroboards.de)) is an error: at the top over the header(and navigation) there is a white space, don't know why? Maybe you know this? I don't want post my whole code here, you can check it out with rightclick->...!

Second question, why ist the color of the navigation and the news-article heading (i mean the background-color) not the same like [here](https://picroma.com/)? If i didn't looked the color up wrong, at both it is: `#161616`??

Thank you!

**LINK FIXED**

Comment: Looks like your site is not currently available. I can not see it.

Comment: website not working. For white space - check paddings, margins

Comment: The link which you added (mikroboards.ds) isnt working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your UL (list) has a top margin of 1em -- this is standard webkit margin, which you can override.
2. The nav & heading colours are both #151515. That seems fine to me.

Comment: nono, my site is mikroboards.de, there is no wrapper

Comment: 1em margin is pretty standard.